# Repeated Output, have to end the program manually

Tags: java

I am a beginner and not tried the following program which is giving me repeated output.. I have to end the program manually in eclipse. Not able to figure out the problem. Please advice. Any other tips are welcome.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sales_Amount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final double Base_Salary = 25000;
        double Commission = 0;
        double Total_Salary;
        double X;
        double Y;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );

        System.out.print("Enter Sales Amount:     ");
        double Sales = input.nextDouble();


        while (Commission < 25001) {

            if (Sales <= 5000); {
                Total_Salary = Base_Salary + (0.08 * Sales);
                System.out.print(" Total Salary for " + Sales + "worth of Sales is:     " + Total_Salary);
            }

            if (Sales > 5000 && Sales < 10001); {
                X = Sales - 5000;
                Total_Salary = Base_Salary + (0.08 * 5000) + (0.10 * X);
                System.out.print(" Total Salary for " + Sales + "worth of Sales is:     " + Total_Salary);
            }

            if (Sales > 10001); {
                Y = Sales - 10000;
                Total_Salary = Base_Salary + (.08 * 5000) + (.10 * 10000) + (.12 * Y);
                System.out.print(" Total Salary for " + Sales + "worth of Sales is:     " + Total_Salary);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've formatted your code for readability because as posted your code formatting was terrible. In the future I strongly recommend that you do this yourself. Formatting is very important because if your code is not in a standard accepted format, it's not very readable, and if it's not readable, it's not understandable.

Comment: You never increment commission anywhere, it remains at 0 so the while loop never ends. Also, addressing the formatting, ctrl + a, then ctrl + i, should format all of your code in ecplise if you didn't already know.

Comment: Your commission never changes. It's (zero) always less than 25001. Hence, forever!

Answer (score 0):

Add commission++ before the end of the loop.